# Regex for password, I am getting error

Tags: javascript, regex

Regex left for 
(Must not contain sequences of letters or numbers) and 
(Do not repeat a number or letter more than 5 times).

I know its repeated question but I was not able to find combination of my requirement. When I tried to combine I was getting errors

Other than that I was able to do it
I was trying for not repeating more than 5 but this one is not working

```
`^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])((.)\2{0,4}(?!\2)).{6,15}$`
```

Partially working one is `^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{6,15}$` I need to both conditions in it.

Comment: Why are you trying to squeeze all your rules into a single unreadable regex? You can test a string multiple times against different conditions in JS.

Comment: Well you can delete questions you posted actually

Comment: You should read [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, have a RegExp that checks the string for allowed characters first. That should be simple and easy to read.

Then if that passes, split the string into an array of each character, loop over it, and check counts for each character. Something like Lodash would help with the latter, but you could write it in plain javascript too.

```
if (/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]$/.test(password)) {
    const chars = password.split('');
    const counts = {};
    chars.forEach(char => {
        if (counts[char] && counts[char] > 5) {
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            counts[char] = counts[char] ? counts[char] + 1 : 1;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I was able to do it using regEx ^.*(.).*(\1.*){4,}.*$

Comment: Are you sure the regexp restricts the password to what you were hoping for? You're matching for any character by using .

Comment: Are you sure the regexp restricts the password to what you were hoping for? You're matching for any character by using .

Comment: I am using ! for that like !(regEx.test(..))

Comment: What I mean is does your regexp work as you intend. You're no longer restricting it to alphanumeric characters